# What's the difference between defining _isMounted as a variable vs as state?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I am using _isMounted to make sure that a callback does not fire after my component unmounts, but realized that if I defined _isMounted as state my data won't populate, but once I defined it as a variable, it works. Why is that?

_isMounted in state:

```
state = {
  _isMounted: false }
```

_isMounted as a variable:

```
_isMounted = false;

state = {...}
```

Comment: Can you share the part where you change `_isMounted`?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is simply the fact that changing an (instance) variable won't cause a rerender. This technique was historically used when an asynchronous call has been created in a component and its completion handler could run when the component has been already unmounted. Trying to save loaded data into state (or even access state) of an unmounted component would cause an error.

A better solution would be to cancel the request when unmounting, or, even better, move the calls completely outside your component and separate `state` and data loading from rendering.